# Как отключить SSLv3 на Apache?

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl

На сервере CentOS 7 установлен Apache 2 4 6, нужно отключить протокол ssl v3.

Гугль говорит, что для этого нужно открыть файл /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf, дописать строку `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2` до `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3` и перезапустить apache.

Я правлю строку, сохраняю файл, перезапускаю apache (sudo service httpd restart), в ответ: `redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart httpd.service`.

Проверяю командой `openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect localhost:443` - коннектится, так будто я и не менял файл ssl.conf.

Как правильно отключить SSLv3?

Comment: а если файл ssl.conf переименовать в ssl_.conf иперезапустить апач?

Comment: [How to disable SSLv3 in Apache?][1]


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162478/how-to-disable-sslv3-in-apache

Comment: norbornen, я видел эту тему, там спрашивавшему не помогли, на сколько я понял.

Comment: Вадим, попробовал переиминовывать, никаких изменений к локалхосту коннектится, на онлайн сервисах пишется, что sslv3 включен. Должно же это о чем то говорить, какая нибудь бредовая идея может оказаться верной, например что если в каком то файле есть строка SSLProtocol all которая переписывает подобную строку в ssl.conf или этот файл вообще игнорируется или сервер не рестартуется из-за какой нибудь ошибки, о которой в консоле почему то не сообщается или еще что нибудь в этом роде.

Comment: для проверки можно рестартануть сам сервер. а переименование для проверки - если нет ошибок в логах и ничего неменяется, скорее всего этот файл не обрабатывается. для подтверждения этого можно в него записать какую-нибудь лабуду однозначно вызывающую ошибки.